# What's the Greek equivalent of "Skin in the Game"?

Tags: greek, idiom

The French equivalent is "Mettre sa peau sur la Table" or "Put your Skin on the Table".

Basically this aphorism is explained under the Hammurabi Code in handling risks: If an engineer had to build a bridge then he should sleep under it for a certain period.

I checked Plato's Republic and couldn't find something close.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Glad you made it. I'm sure you'll find people here more welcoming than the other two sites.

Comment: I think such question should better be in Mythology stack. Not sure 

Comment: We do handle Greek questions, so it might be on-topic here. A moderator would know best.

Comment: @Leb_Broth As an once-avid member of Mythology.SE, it would be deleted instantaneously.

Comment: @ktm5124 This question is clearly on-topic here. I'd like to know the answer to the corresponding question about Latin, too. I hope someone asks it.

Comment: Can you give a complete sentence in which you want to use this expression in Greek? Context is always helpful for this type of question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure there is an equivalent phrasal idiom in Greek, but the verb [συγκινδυνεύω](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dsugkinduneu%2Fw) "run a risk together with someone" can be used to express this idea; here's an example from Plato's *Philebus* (29a):

> βούλει δῆτά τι καὶ ἡμεῖς τοῖς ἔμπροσθεν ὁμολογούμενον συμφήσωμεν ὡς ταῦθ᾽ οὕτως ἔχει, καὶ μὴ μόνον οἰώμεθα δεῖν τἀλλότρια ἄνευ κινδύνου λέγειν, ἀλλὰ καὶ **συγκινδυνεύωμεν** καὶ μετέχωμεν τοῦ ψόγου, ὅταν ἀνὴρ δεινὸς φῇ ταῦτα μὴ οὕτως ἀλλ᾽ ἀτάκτως ἔχειν;

Harold Fowler's translation: "Do you, then, think we should assent to this and agree in the doctrine of our predecessors, not merely intending to repeat the words of others, with no risk to ourselves, but ready to **share with them in the risk** and the blame, if any clever man declares that this world is not thus ordered, but is without order?"